# my PC controller is not working only for 1 game

Tags: pc, controllers, hitman-absolution

I have been playing hitman absolution for a while with my controller and now the controller is not working for this game(only the home button is working) but the controller is working normally with other games.
Can someone help me ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

> Some gamepads support both DirectInput and XInput modes. These
>   gamepads can be identified by a switch on them that has two options,
>   “D” (DirectInput) and “X” (XInput).
>
> To play Hitman: Absolution a gamepad must be supported and **set to
>   DirectInput mode.**
>
> http://support.feralinteractive.com/docs/en/hitmanabsolution/1.1.1/steam/faqs/?access=eBpPndmrVq#i_direct_input

I'm going to assume you have one of the logitec controllers, previously used DirectInput, then switched to XInput either by accident or to play another game, but now forgot to switch back?

Comment: yes, I am using a Logitech controller, all the games in my PC used Xinput but still, I tried with both the inputs and the controller does not work with that game do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @PurusothShanmugarajah No other solutions, but one more option on the initial one: It may require being set to D from before you launch the program, setting it to D after the game has launched may not be enough. I do not know if that's the case, but it's worth checking out.